# InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:234)

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am developing a servlet which returns some JSON objects, when I call this servlet from the browser, everything is fine, when the font-end developer call that from JavaScript, after 4 or 5 requests this exception is thrown:

```
14-Aug-2014 17:32:50.488 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Wkr570Controller] in context with path [] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:234)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:189)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.commit(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:739)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:178)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:523)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteChars(OutputBuffer.java:474)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.flushBuffer(CharChunk.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.append(CharChunk.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:184)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If anybody should arrive here after two years:

This seems to be an error in Tomcat.

See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58646

Update your Tomcat to version 8.0.33 or newer. That should work. For fixes of Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7 see at the bottom of the bug report which I've linked.